# Dry up Rails Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on DRYing up an API. Everything has been going well but I've noticed that the twenty lines or so of each class is almost the same:

```
class V1::FooController < V1::BaseController
  # documentation
  swagger_controller :Foo, "Foo"
  # authorization
  before_filter      :allow_session_user
  before_filter      :allow_api_key_user, only: [:sample,   :index]
  before_filter      :check_access
  # inherit crud endpoints
  inherit_resources
  actions :all, :except => [ :index, :show ]
  # other
  before_filter      :private_foo_method
  respond_to         :json

  #...other stuff...#
end
```

I'd like to DRY these up but the problem is I need to run these callbacks in the context of the current class I'm in (and not the super class). For the `before_filters` I know you could usually just move those up to `V1::BaseController`, but in my case it would cause issues with the order of execution because I have other `before_filters` in `V1::BaseController`.

```
class V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
    #this needs to execute in the context of the class that called it and NOT V1::BaseController
    def super_init(documentation_name, allowed_api_endpoints, except_inherited_crud)
        swagger_controller documentation_name, documentation_name
        inherit_resources
        # authorization
        before_filter      :allow_session_user
        before_filter      :allow_api_key_user, only: allowed_api_endpoints
        before_filter      :check_access
        # inherit crud endpoints
        inherit_resources
        actions :all, :except => except_inherited_crud
        # other
        respond_to         :json
    end

end

class V1::FooController < V1::BaseController
    before_filter :init
    before_filter :private_foo_method

    def init
        # super_init should run in the context of V1::FooController
        super.super_init("Foo", [:sample,   :index], [ :index, :show ])
    end

    #...other stuff...#
end
```

I tried passing in `self` to `super_init` and putting all the logic inside a `class << passed_context` but that didn't work. I could give a list of stuff I tried but I'm not sure how helpful that would be to anyone...

If you need any more information please ask. I have a feeling this is some higher level abstraction here that I haven't had to do in Rails before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [prepend_before_action](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/prepend_before_action)? That gives you a little more control over the order of execution.

On a side note, it'd be great to use `before_action` instead of `before_filter` since the `before_action` syntax [will be deprecated soon](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193)

Comment: We're on an old version of Rails so we've been using filter.

Comment: Ok, you can use `prepend_before_filter` in the meantime.